# Why does selecting/updating on inner-join take so much longer on higher IDs and is threr a way around it?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, inner-join

I have two tables, one with ~250k records one with ~1.5M records.

I am doing a Select and/or Update using Inner Join.

It hung so I decided to to in batches e.g.

```
Where ID<100000
```

then

```
Where ID>=100000 and ID<200000
```

with each successive batch it takes longer and longer.  Adding to the issue of course is there might be records that would have joined w/o being separated by batches.

I'm curious why that is (why do the first 100k IDs join fast and the last 100k take so much longer) and if there is a way to do as a single query w/o the IDs becoming a/the issue (if they in fact are).

Comment: What are the indexes on the table? Could you post the 2 [execution plans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html)?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `UPDATE`.  100K batch size is too big; 1K _might_ be faster.  It could be that the `JOIN` is less efficient than it needs to be.